# Uploading directly to Amazon S3 with jQuery fileupload plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload files to S3 on my Rails app (Installed this gem: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails).

This is my form. As I just need the file uploaded and create the document later, it is not a form_for.

```
  <%= form_tag 'Bucket URL SNIP', :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'key', @token %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'AWSAccessKeyId', ACCESSKEYSNIP %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'acl', 'public-read' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'success_action_status', '200' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'policy', controller.s3_policy_document %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'signature', controller.signature %>
  <% end %>
```

And the jQuery uploader is initialized like this:

```
  $(function () {

      $('#fileupload').fileupload({

        forceIframeTransport: true

      });

  });
```

Everything works, I see the UI, but when the file's progress bar finishes, it gives me an error and the file doesn't actually get uploaded.

TypeError: iframe is undefined. (Firefox)
TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (Chrome)

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

Looking at the Javascript console, I get an error like this (replaced the real addresses):

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL BUCKETURL from frame with URL SERVERURL. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: can you share the policy document ?

Comment: http://ideone.com/9f4XD

Generic bucket name, the token is the same as in the form

Comment: put  'starts-with', '$key', '' instead of 'starts-with', '$key', #{token}

Comment: Nope. I'm using a Flash based uploader now, which works fine, but I'll leave the question as-is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently wrote a short tutorial about how to upload directly files to s3, hopefully it'll help you :

http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/

Comment: Does your code work the same way for uploads not backed by a model? It strikes me as rather unnecessary to go to your server, still.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon AWS recently announced support for CORS. This means you don't have to use the iframe method for direct upload to S3. Now you can use HTML5 without worries.

It will also allow you to use features such as drag and drop.

To enable direct HTML5 upload, you just have to adjust your bucket CORS setting in the bucket properties.

Comment: Very useful piece of information if you want to make progressbar work. In the official docu (24.05.2018) it is told to use `forceIframeTransport: true`. But that is not necessary anymore and if set to true, the progressbar wont work.